# while trying to create a migration, I keep getting "Can't find executable rails"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

While trying to create a migration, i ran into this problem, any ideas?

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:335:in `bin_path': can't find executable rails for rails-3.2.2  (Gem::Exception)
from /usr/bin/rails:19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
bundle exec rails
```

instead of just `rails`. This ensures the command is run/found in the context of your Gemfile.